# Convert RGB to HSI manually in Python

Tags: python, image, rgb, hsv, converters

I have an assignment due and need some help.

So, I need to convert RGB from an image to HSI and print out three images (1. Hue, 2. Saturation and 3. Intensity).

I can't use any libraries beside openCV for loading and printing the image; anything else must be done manually.

I have got (I think) the calculations right but I can't seem to print of correctly. I telling me that I can't since the input is a tuple and the output isn't. So, my output (put.pixel) is empty right now.

Hope anyone can help!!

```
import math
from PIL import Image

RgbString = ' :RGB for pixel: '
HsiString = ' :HSI for pixel: '

img = Image.open('MemeFace.jpg')
HImage = Image.new("HSV", (img.width, 
img.height))
rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgb_img.getpixel((1, 1))
HImage.convert('HSV')


def rgb2hsv(r, g, b):
    r = float(r)
    g = float(g)
    b = float(b)
    high = max(r, g, b)
    low = min(r, g, b)
    h, s, v = high, high, high

    d = high - low
    s = 0 if high == 0 else d/high

    if high == low:
        h = 0.0
    else:
        h = {
            r: (g - b) / d + (6 if g < b 
    else 0),
            g: (b - r) / d + 2,
            b: (r - g) / d + 4,
        }[high]
        h /= 6

    return h,s,v



for x in range (1, img.width):
    for y in range (1, img.height):
        r, g, b = rgb_img.getpixel((x,y))

        print(r, g, b, RgbString,  x, y)
        print(rgb2hsv(r, g, b), 
        HsiString, x, y)


        HImage.putpixel((x, y), ())


Image._show(HImage)

Image.fromdef
```

Comment: What kind of output do you want? Do you have some example? You may want just black and white images, so or you select the output as BW image, or you construct a triplet with (h, h, h), one with (s, s, s) and one with (v, v, ). [I prefer the first one with most saturated colours and higher value, but we do not know from your question[